# Inverse complex tangent in two forms

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

I have one doubt, I'm studying complex trigonometric functions and in the books I've seen there are two versions of the inverse tangent. I've seen: $$\tan^{-1}(z) = \frac{1}{2i} \log \frac{1+zi}{1-zi}$$

and, as well: $$\tan^{-1}(z) =  \frac{i}{2} \log \frac{i+z}{i-z} $$

How are these two the same? Thanks in advance.

Comment: I would first set expr.1 = expr.2. Then you can solve this equation via algebra. Eliminate the $\log$ out of the equation ;).

Answer (score 1):

firstly $\frac{1}{2i} =-\frac{i}{2}$

Multiplying the expression inside the log by $i\over i$ ...
$$ \frac{1+zi}{1-zi} \times {i\over i}= \frac{i-z}{i+z}  $$
so $$\log \frac{1+zi}{1-zi} = - \log \frac{i+z}{i-z} $$

Comment: Thanks, this is much clearer. Just one question, in the last equality, if when we multiply the inside of log by $\frac{i}{i}$ we would have $\log \frac{i-z}{i+z}$, right? After that how is $\log \frac{i-z}{i+z} = - \log \frac{i+z}{i-z}$ ? Or is it something involving the $\frac{i}{i}$ multiplication?

Comment: It is always true that $\log(\frac 1x) = -\log(x)$